# Story about Moon being hit by an Asteroid and causing Freezing on Earth

Tags: books, moon, story-identification

A while back in 2012-13 I read a book with following plot line:

1. It  was about the moon being hit by an asteroid which caused it to move closer the the Earth causing a massive freeze.
2. The book follows the perspective of a boy who tries to survive in a
   city (can't remember name) with his two sisters.

I read this book back when I was a kid.

Comment: When did you use to be a kid? Add the year and more details to help identify the story

Answer (score 7):

Could it be part of "The Last Survivors" trilogy by Susan Beth Pfeffer?

The first book, [Life as we knew it](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/213753.Life_As_We_Knew_It) was published in 2006.

The description provided on Good Reads is:

> Miranda’s disbelief turns to fear in a split second when **a meteor
>   knocks the moon closer to the earth**. How should her family prepare
>   for the future when worldwide tsunamis wipe out the coasts,
>   earthquakes rock the continents, and volcanic ash blocks out the sun?
>   As **summer turns to Arctic winter**, **Miranda, her two brothers**,
>   and their mother retreat to the unexpected safe haven of their
>   sunroom, where **they subsist on stockpiled food and limited water in
>   the warmth of a wood-burning stove**.
>
> Told in journal entries, this is the heart-pounding story of Miranda’s
>   struggle to hold on to the most important resource of all--hope--in an
>   increasingly desperate and unfamiliar world.

**Similarities:**

- Moon is hit by a meteor.
- Moon comes closer to Earth
- Earth's climate changes as a result.
- Summer changes to arctic winter.
- Kids try to survive.

**Differences:**

- Told from POV of a girl named Myranda instead of a boy.
- The girl has two brothers unlike your description where the boy has two sisters.
- There is also the role of their mother.
- The climate change is not limited to winter only

The second book in the series ([The Dead and the Gone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dead_and_the_Gone)) may be a closer match as it follows the perspective of a boy and his 2 sisters in a city. From Wikipedia's synopsis:

> The Dead and the Gone follows 17-year-old **Alex Morales and his**
>   **sisters, Briana and Julie**, in their struggle to survive after an
>   **asteroid hits the Moon and knocks it out of orbit, closer to Earth**.
>   Taking place in New York, they are plagued with **volcanic eruptions,**
>   tsunamis and tidal waves, and earthquakes, along with famine caused by
>   **food shortages and disease** that kill millions of people in the
>   process. Alex is forced to take care of his sisters in the absence of
>   his mother and father and to raid dead bodies for valuables to trade
>   for food. He struggles with his religious faith while **trying**
>   **desperately to survive**.

Comment: The sequel [The Dead and the Gone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dead_and_the_Gone) is from the POV of a boy with 2 sisters living in a city.

Comment: @Fruitbat Splendid. Would you like to add it as answer because the sequel seems to be more in line with the OP's description than Part 1?

Comment: @Aegon As you've correctly identified the series, I'm happy to edit your answer with some detail from the second book (I think my daughter has it somewhere).

Comment: @Aegon I've add the Wikipedia summary for now. I don't know when I'll find the book, although I suspect that the summary will be enough as it answers the second part of the question.

Comment: @Fruitbat I have made the post community wiki because it doesn't feel right to not to give you the credit. Please do make it better when you find the book, if you wish so.

Comment: The second book is what I was looking for. It was back in around 2012-13 when I read it and it was so interesting to see how the characters developed throughout the book. I know I'm not really meant to say thanks in these comments, but I thought you should deserve some praise

Comment: @George Glad to hear that George. If you are satisfied that this is the correct answer, then you should mark it as accepted answer so that other people could identify it as such  as well.

Comment: @Aegon how does one do that?

Comment: @George [Click on the tick-mark icon like shown here](http://imgur.com/a/HDfC0)